# How to create custom functions in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Can you create functions in SQLite like you can in MSSQL?

If so, how? What is the syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 83, accepted):

SQLite does not have a stored function/stored procedure language. So `CREATE FUNCTION` does not work. What you can do though is map functions from a c library to SQL functions (user-defined functions). To do that, use SQLite's C API (see: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html)

If you're not using the C API, your wrapper API may define something that allows you access to this feature, see for example:

- PHP `sqlite_create_function()` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-create-function.php)
- Python  `sqlite3.create_function()` ([http://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_function))
- Perl `$dbh->sqlite_create_function($name,$argc,$code_ref,$flags)` (https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite#$dbh-%3Esqlite_create_function(-$name,-$argc,-$code_ref,-$flags-))

Comment: @Andrew: Since you mention MSSQL, you might be interested to know that SQLite UDFs are  easy to implement in any CLR language using the System.Data.SQLite provider for .NET. http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

Comment: If you map a user-defined function as you mentioned in this answer, does it retain in the sqlite database or do you have to map it every time you load the db?

Comment: Good question. I think you might have to re-map.

Comment: This comment helped me in trying to figure out how to actually write the UDF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867099/how-to-create-a-user-defined-function-in-sqlite

Comment: In case of Python + SQLAlchemy, you can use something like `engine.connect().connection.create_function()` to access the native `create_function()` method of sqlite. Linke: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#working-with-raw-dbapi-connections

Comment: for c# see this blog: https://www.bricelam.net/2017/08/22/sqlite-efcore-udf-all-the-things.html

Comment: what about golang?

Answer (score 9):

This could be useful to many: in *SQLiteStudio* it is possible to define new functions and collations easily from interface through a sql built-in plugin for example.

https://github.com/pawelsalawa/sqlitestudio/wiki/Official_plugins#sql-built-in

Through the function editor.

Comment: Note that: "Custom SQL functions created in SQLiteStudio exist only in context of SQLiteStudio. Functions are not persisted in database, it's just not how SQLite databases work. If you want to use some function in your own application, you have to register that function in SQLite from your application."
https://github.com/pawelsalawa/sqlitestudio/wiki/User_Manual#custom-sql-functions

Answer (score 5):

You can write arbitrary functions in SQL with the [`define`](https://github.com/nalgeon/sqlean/blob/main/docs/define.md) extension:

```sql
-- define a function to sum the numbers 1..n
select define('sumn', ':n * (:n + 1) / 2');

-- use it as a regular function
select sumn(3);
6
select sumn(5);
15
```

Comment: Sqlite does not have the function `define`

Comment: It's an extension.