# C# + SQLite - How to use the functions in queries?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I write under a plain WinCE application, which is involved in SQLite.The project uses System.data.SQLite.dll and SQLite.Interop.080.dll.
So I'm working with SQLite:

```
 SQLiteConnection ConnectSQL = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=D:\1.db");
 ConnectSQL.open();
 SQLiteCommand commandSQL = ConnectSQL.CreateCommand();
 commandSQL.CommandText = "Select Field1 FROM Table1";
 SQLiteDataReader result = commandSQL.ExecuteReader();
```

How to declare the function and use it in sqlite to be able to write:

```
 commandSQL.CommandText = "Select MyFunc(Field1) FROM Table1";
```

Comment: SQLite does not support user defined functions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867099/how-to-create-a-user-defined-function-in-sqlite

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108870/how-to-create-custom-functions-in-sqlite

Comment: Thank you, I read a reference. But the function "CreateFunction" is the internal fuction and belongs System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3, which is also an internal, in that library that I use. Probably have to use sqlite3.dll?