# Update only the year in SQLite column

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite3 database that has 366 rows in it, and a date for each day of the year.  I need to make sure that the year is current, and if it is not, then I need to update the year to the current calendar year.  What I would like to do is something like the following:

```
UPDATE daily SET date = DATE('%Y', 'now');
```

or

```
UPDATE daily SET date = strftime('%Y', 'now');
```

But those queries just make the date column NULL, and even if they did work as I expected them to, I doubt that it would retain the day and month that is there already.

In MySQL, I can do something like `UPDATE daily SET date = ADDDATE(date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)` -- but firstly, it is not a valid SQLite query, and secondly, I need to update to the current year, not just step up one year.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is running a python/other script on the database an option?

Comment: No, unfortunately it is not, since it is an imbedded DB inside a mobile application.  I have to make this logic happen when the app launches, so the dates don't get stale even if the app is dormant for several years on someone's device.

Comment: Could you just read the dates from the app & then write them back to the db?  Or create a custom function to call from the SQL? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108870/how-to-create-custom-functions-in-sqlite).  There might be a non-obvious way to do this with a big strftime function, but seems like it'd be less effort to just use non-sql code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
create table t (id int, d text);

insert into t
select 1, date('2011-01-01') union
select 2, date('2012-03-11') union
select 3, date('2013-05-21') union
select 4, date('2014-07-01') union
select 5, date('2015-11-11');

select * from t;

update t set
    d = date(strftime('%Y', date('now')) || strftime('-%m-%d', d));

select * from t;
```

It uses [Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). Firstly it takes month and day from field (`strftime('-%m-%d', d)`) then add (concatenate) current year (`strftime('%Y', date('now'))`) and converts it to date.

[SQL Fiddle live example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/da6ac/1).

Comment: Thank you, sir!  You made my day.  Not only did it work great, but I was able to learn from your explanation.