# sqlite: Can I mock the current time `now()` for testing?

Tags: unit-testing, sqlite

I build a test suite for a program that runs a lot of SQL statements with `now()` against a sqlite data base.  I would like to mock the sqlite clock --- to test behaviour that is designed to take several days within one second.  I do not want to touch the system clock.

Is this possible with sqlite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example in Python:

```
import sqlite3
def mock(*_):
    return '1984-01-02 11:22:33'
connection = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
print(connection.execute('SELECT DATETIME()').fetchone()[0])
connection.create_function('DATETIME', -1, mock)
print(connection.execute('SELECT DATETIME()').fetchone()[0])
```

Output

```
2022-03-01 11:23:05
1984-01-02 11:22:33
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLite's built-in functions can be redefined with [sqlite3_create_function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html).

[Edit by Yaakov Belch --- additional information:]

- In perl, you can access this API through the [$dbh->sqlite_create_function](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD%3a%3aSQLite#dbh-sqlite_create_function-name-argc-code_ref) method of a DBD::SQLite data base handle.
- For python or PHP see this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108870/how-to-create-custom-functions-in-sqlite/2108921#2108921).

Comment: To make your answer more useful, please consider providing an example of how this can be implemented.