# Grouping by digits or first letter

Tags: sqlite, group-by, grouping

If I run the following query I get the results as expected:

```
SELECT upper(substr(columnname, 1, 1)) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY upper(substr(columnname, 1, 1)).
```

I get groups for every starting letter from A to Z and 0 to 9. But what I want to have is that I get groups like "0-9", "A-C", "D-F" and so on. I have no ideas how to group groups. Can anybody give me a hint how to start please?

Comment: How are these 'super-groups' determined?  Are they static and known in advance, or are they somehow data-driven?

Answer (score 0):

One idea could be to create a user-defined function that receives one letter and returns a string with the group to which the letter belongs.

If you name that function "getGroupFor" and it works so that:

```
getGroupFor('A') returns 'A-C'
getGroupFor('B') returns 'A-C'
... (and so on)
```

Then you can change your select to group by the output of that function.

```
SELECT getGroupFor(upper(substr(columnname, 1, 1))) FROM table GROUP BY getGroupFor(upper(substr(columnname, 1, 1)))
```

You can find how to create user-defined functions for SQLLite by looking at this other question:

[How to create custom functions in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108870/how-to-create-custom-functions-in-sqlite)

Another way would be to create a table that can map letters to letter-groups, then join the tables and group by the "letter-group" column instead of by the individual letters.