# Sqlite - Replace html tags with only a specific set of attributes

Tags: sqlite

I have a large table in my sqlite database with a thousands of entries in a field that hold blocks of text.

In the many paragraphs contained in those entries, there is an html tag that recurs regularly that is formatted like this:

`<span class="emphasis bold">EXAMPLE TEXT</span>`

I would like to replace these tags with simple `<b></b>` tags.

Therefore, the above example would be reformatted to look like this:

`<b>EXAMPLE TEXT</b>`

When I say there are many paragraphs in these entries, that means that several of these tags can appear in a single entry. And, it is not the only html that appears. There are even other `<span>` tags with different attributes, which makes this a bit tricky.

So, whatever sqlite command I come up with, it needs to be able to replace each occurrence of only the `<span>` tags with the classes `emphasis` and `bold`.

If the paragraph looked this:

```
This is a <span class="emphasis bold">PERFECT</span> example of
what <span class="keep-this-tag">I AM TRYING TO</span> accomplish.
```

After the sqlite command is run, it should look like this:

```
This is a <b>PERFECT</b> example of
what <span class="keep-this-tag">I AM TRYING TO</span> accomplish.
```

As you can see, only the first tag was changed and not the second one, even though they are both `<span>` tags, because I only want to change the `<span>` tags with the attributes `emphasis` and `bold`.

How do you think I can tackle this problem?

Comment: If you really need to remove an arbitrary number of `<span>` tags from a paragraph of text, then you will have a very hard time doing so with core SQLite functions.  The best tool for this might be a regex replacement, but SQLite does not support this out of the box.  Perhaps you can handle this replacement using an app language like Java or C#?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was thinking that might be the case, but was hoping someone knew more than me and could save me the trouble of having to go that route!

Comment: You could define a UDF for regex replacement and use that (but maybe not if running SQLite on Android).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm doing the work on a Macbook and using the "DB Browser for SQLite" app to manipulate the DB and execute commands. Not sure if you've used it. How would I go about doing a UDF with regex?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108870/how-to-create-custom-functions-in-sqlite) and [here](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html).  I've never done this myself, I can only tell you that need some pretty heavy fire power to scrub your data the way you want it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Never try to [parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348)! It would be a better idea to use a real HTML or XML parser.

Comment: @CL. When I commented the above, I had in mind that the OP only wanted to replace isolated `<span>` tags all at the same top level.  Regex _could_ do this, although of course a parser is the way to go, and in any case SQLite would not even support a regex replacement.