# What to replace uuid_generate_v4() by?

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, nestjs, typeorm

I have a NestJS project where I generate the migration with `typeorm:generate-migration`. Because of `uuid_generate_v4()` the script is not cross compatible between PostgreSQL (dev/prod) and SQLite (tests). How to make it work?

User Entity :

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;
}
```

Migration :

```
export class initUser1667668869578 implements MigrationInterface {
    name = 'initUser1667668869578'

    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`CREATE TABLE "user" ("id" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(), "name" character varying NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "PK_cace4a159ff9f2512dd42373760" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))`);
    }

    public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE "user"`);
    }

}
```

The error (caused because SQLite doesn't have `uuid_generate_v4()`) :

> Migration "initUser1667668869578" failed, error: SQLITE_ERROR: near "(": syntax error

Comment: as your migrations are written in pure SQL, I guess you cannot switch to SQLite easily.

Comment: Why would you test on an environment that’s very different from production?

Comment: https://phauer.com/2017/dont-use-in-memory-databases-tests-h2/

Answer (score 0):

Natively there's nothing you can replace that function call with. Alternatives:

1. Drop `NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4()` part and use a `trigger after insert` instead. [Example.](https://www.kittell.net/code/auto-increment-auto-generate-guid/)
2. Define your own `uuid_generate_v4()` - you will need [an extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2108921/5298879) for that.
3. If `dev` and `prod` are on PostgreSQL, it would make sense to run your tests on PostgreSQL as well, unless you're just testing whether it'd be possible to migrate.
4. Drop the db-side default value part entirely and generate it in the app.