# How to print function parameter's value?

Tags: function, sqlite, sqlitestudio

In SQLiteStudio 3.3.3 I created a function. How can I print parameter `args1`'s value in the area "`Function implementation code`"?

[image]

Error:

> No such column: arg1

Comment: SQLite doesn't support user-functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108870/how-to-create-custom-functions-in-sqlite - SqliteStudio fakes it by using its own Sqlite Extension, which means you can't necessarily use the functions you define in application/library code unless you also load the same extension there, which may be impossible in some cases (e.g. when targeting iOS, I assume).

Comment: @Dai Okay, so why do we have the Input arguments field?

Comment: Because you **can** define and use functions within SqliteStudio - just not necessarily in your user-facing applications (which would use SQLite without SqliteStudio's functions-support extension). I don't know if that's what you want though.

Comment: yes this is what i want

Comment: Haven'tt you read SqliteStudio's [documentation - it's right there](https://github.com/pawelsalawa/sqlitestudio/wiki/User_Manual#custom-sql-functions)? (note the boldtext warning at the bottom: _"Custom SQL functions created in SQLiteStudio exist only in context of SQLiteStudio. Functions are not persisted in database, it's just not how SQLite databases work. If you want to use some function in your own application, you have to register that function in SQLite from your application."_)

Comment: yes, but I didn't see an example of how to create a function with a parameter, just the use of the function. Correct me if I'm wrong https://github.com/pawelsalawa/sqlitestudio/wiki/User_Manual#custom-sql-functions

Comment: Version 3.3.x of SQLiteStudio did not handle names of declared function arguments, only in upcoming 3.4.0 version it is handled as expected. In 3.3 you should `SELECT ?` to use 1st argument and use subsequent `?` marks for subsequent parameters from function.

Comment: Also please note, that SQLiteStudio is actively supported on its "GitHub Discussions" page.